# modelMapper: ObjectiveDto cannot be cast to class ObjectiveModel

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have an issue with modelMapper while mapping List of object:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ObjectiveDto>>() {}.getType();
List<ObjectiveModel> objectiveModels =
        modelMapper.map(objectiveDtos, listType);
```

At this stage it works fine. My issue is when I try to iterate the list in a for loop.

```
for (ObjectiveModel objectiveModel: objectiveModels) {
    objectiveModel.setObjectiveKeyId(utils.generateId(30));
    objectiveModel.setProject(projectModel);
}
```

I obtain an error message:

```
2020-11-09 12:42:42.924 DEBUG 14956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.ClassCastException: class fr.domain.dto.ObjectiveDto cannot be cast to class fr.domain.model.ObjectiveModel (fr.domain.dto.ObjectiveDto and fr.domain.model.ObjectiveModel are in unnamed module of loader 'app')]
```

It seems that I can't iterate a list in a for loop because of modelmapper cast issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real “error” is in the section that you say “works fine”.

According to the example in http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/ModelMapper.html#map-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type-

That explicitly shows that the `map(source, Type)`  method returns a List with the generic type (therefore objects in the List) of the TypeToken - String in the Javadoc, ObjectiveDto in your case. The Exception in your `for` is therefore correct.

No compilation error was returned when you assigned to List since the generics signature of `map(Object source, Type destinationType)` did not tie the return type to the `Type` parameter (nor, of course, would there be a runtime error since due to type erasure all there was returned was a List).   You should therefore change your original assignment to :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ObjectiveDto>>() {}.getType();
List<ObjectiveDto> objectiveModels =
    modelMapper.map(objectiveDtos, listType);
```

Or

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ObjectiveModel>>() {}.getType();
List<ObjectiveModel> objectiveModels =
    modelMapper.map(objectiveDtos, listType);
```

Comment: The following line is Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand - following line from what ?

Comment: in my log i have the cast error message, once I enter the loop  i directly have a 500 error

Comment: That is correct - your List contains ObjectiveDto objects since that’s what you specified in your TypeToken.   If you want it to contain ObjectiveModel objects, then change your TypeToken as per my “Or” example above.